# Mail sent through Rails app is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

I'm trying to set up a contact form on my Rails app but although a email is send and recieved the content of the email is empty.

This is the body of the email

```
!!!
%html
  %body
    %p
      = @message.name
      Schreef het volgende:
    %p= @message.email
    %p= @message.message
```

So at the moment I'm only getting `Schreef het volgende` in my email.

My MessagesController

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

    def create
      @message = Message.new(message_params)
      if @message.valid?
        # TODO send message here
        Messages.new_messages_email(@messages).deliver
        redirect_to root_url, notice: "Message sent! Thank you for contacting us."
      else
        redirect_to root_url, notice: "Something went wrong, try again!"
      end
    end

    private
    def message_params
      params.require(:message).permit(
        :name, 
        :message,
        :email
      )
    end
end
```

My Messages model

```
class Message
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  attr_accessor :name, :email, :message

  validates_presence_of :name
  validates :email, :email_format => {:message => 'is not looking good'}
  validates_length_of :message, :maximum => 500

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
    end
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end
end
```

My Messages mailer,

```
class Messages < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "info@domein.nl"

    def new_messages_email(message)

    @message = Message.new
    mail(to: 'peter@no-illusions.nl',
        subject: 'Iemand wilt contact met U')
    end
end
```

And the form

```
= form_for @message do |f|
  .field
    %br/
    = f.text_field :name, :placeholder => "Naam"
  .field
    %br/
    = f.text_field :email, :placeholder => "Emailadres"
  .field
    %br/
    = f.text_area :message, :rows => 5, :placeholder => "Uw bericht"
  .actions= f.submit "Verstuur bericht", :id => "submit"
```

I'm trying to do set this up without storing the emails in a database. Does anyone know why the content put in the fields isn't send in the email?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have very similar issue to the previous one :-) .

First, `Messages.new_messages_email(@messages).deliver`. Not `@messages`, but `@message`. Second:

```
class Messages < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "info@domein.nl"

    def new_messages_email(message)

      @message = message # See the difference?
      mail(to: 'peter@no-illusions.nl', subject: 'Iemand wilt contact met U')
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. It's working now. This stuff is pretty hard to bugfix since there's no error log to be found.

Comment: Yep. In Ruby world, you can call whatever instance variable you want, e.g: `@bleh` and it will simply return `nil`. So that it didn't complain about `@messages`. Another thing is that you haven't used passed `message` anywhere, just used `@message = Message.new` and that was just fine. In any static typed language (C, Java), compiler would complain about that `messages` variable, however Ruby is dynamic and hence, evaluated at runtime.